# How can i return a matrix?

Tags: arrays, pointers, matrix

I have this code

```
int draw_matrix(int a){

  int matrix[a][a];
  int i,j;

  for(i=0;i<a;i++){
      for(j=0;j<a;j++){
          matrix[i][j]=0;
        }
      }

  int ship;
  for (ship=0;ship<5;ship++){
    if (a==8){
      if (ship==0){
        int x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4;
        printf("... \n");
        scanf("%i %i %i %i", &x1, &x2, &x3, &x4);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("... \n");
        scanf("%i %i %i %i",&y1,&y2,&y3,&y4);
        fflush(stdin);
        matrix[x1-1][y1-1]=1;
        matrix[x2-1][y2-1]=1;
        matrix[x3-1][y3-1]=1;
        matrix[x4-1][y4-1]=1;
        }
      if (ship==1){...
      .
      .
      .
  }
return 0;
}
```

this code is for a game and i need to call this function to use a matrix in the other function but i don't know how to return this matrix...

can anybody tell me how to do it? (I'm working in C not C++)

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be of type `int **`, and you should have `return matrix;` at the bottom instead of `return 0;`

Also, you should initialize matrix like this:

```
int **matrix;
matrix = new int*[a];
int i,j;

for(i=0;i<a;i++){
  matrix[i] = new int[a];
  for(j=0;j<a;j++){
      matrix[i][j]=0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: When i compile it it says something like "warning: return from incompatible pointer type" and "warning: function returns address of local variable [enabled by default]"

Comment: what is "new" for you? compiler says that i must declare it first.

Comment: @SantiagoPáez The new operator...not sure why the compiler wouldn't recognize it...what compiler are you using?

Comment: i'm using a virtual machine of Ubuntu... and i'm compiling in the terminal.

Comment: @SantiagoPáez Via what compiler?

Comment: i don't know the name of the compiler... is called just "Terminal- Ubuntu@DigSys-VM"

Comment: @SantiagoPáez If you don't even know what compiler you're using I'm not sure how you expect to do much...